# How to search for measures, corresponding to a specific project version?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am using SonarQube 6.4 (build 25310, self-hosted). I'm able to search using id as demonstrated by this URL:

https://sonarqube.localhost.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/history?id=%AWESOME_API%

What other parameters can I use? I would want to search for a specific version that has been scanned.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [measures/search_history service](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures/search_history). It doesn't give you a version parameter, but you can search by date. So pinpoint your date using the [project_analyses/search service](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/project_analyses/search), and then search for measures by date.

Note that file level measures are only retained for the most recent analysis.

Comment: Is there a way to add another parameter besides id - what about version? :) https://sonarqube.cool.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/history?id=AWSESOME-API